# Google Maps javascript code-behind visual studio

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this javascript code  in C# file code-behind:

```
  string markers = @"var address = '" + txtLocal.Text + @"';
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
        title: address,
      position: results[0].geometry.location
  });
```

});"
;

```
 Literal1.Text = @"
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var mapOptions = { zoom: 15,    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID  };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);"
        + markers + @"
    }
 </script>";
```

I have this piece of code in the .aspx file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBF-_RUuJxittvOu3E0SwutoD8LU3BZkPI"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,visualization&sensor=false"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript"> 
         $(function () {
         initialize();
        });
 </script>

        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px" />
```

I made a few changes and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `myMap`   in markers  and not `map-canvas` eg:

```
 @"map: myMap });";
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in your code

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': " + txtLocal.Text + "}," +
                             @"map: map_canvas });";
```

@"map: map_canavas should say:

```
@"map: myMap
```

Or you can try adding this to your code too:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=>>>>>YOUR_API_KEY<<<<<<">
</script>
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,visualization&sensor=false">


<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function () {
        initialize();
    });
</script>
```

To get your Api Key try:
[https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/signup?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you for your answer: I corrected the first error and add the other code, but nothing still happens.

Comment: You should need a google maps Api Key, try: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial